# Get value of selected item in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the value from the selected item when I click a button.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p class="own"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImageDatafromDB.aspx?id=" + System.Convert.ToString(Eval("ID")) %>' Width="230" Height="250"/>
            <br />
            <span class="own1" style="width:230px;"><br /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="1.2em" ForeColor="White"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Direktor :" style="color:#06D85F; float:left"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="InFo" Text='<%# Eval("fattare") %>' Font-Italic="true"/> 
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Year : " style="color:#06D85F; float:left;"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="InFo" runat="server" Text=' <%# (Eval("Ar")) %>' />
            </br>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Visa" CommandName="ButtonClick"/>
            </span>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hemsida"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (conn)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Movies", conn);
            ad.Fill(dt);
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {
        Label myTempLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("Label6");

        myTempLabel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I get all of the names of all of the items, but I only want to get the name of the selected item.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a where clause in your select statement with a parameter passing the name of the desired param to the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the ItemCommand event of DataList1, paste the following code:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataList1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    myTempLabel.Text = "You selected: " + ((Label)DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
    myTempLabel.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use SelectedItem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (DataList1.SelectedItem != null)
     {
        Label myTempLabel = (Label)DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("Label6");
        myTempLabel.Visible = true;
     }
 }
```

Try changing this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Visa" CommandName="ButtonClick"/>
```

to This:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Visa" OnClick="Button1_Click"
/>
```

Another alternative is to remove the code in the button and handle it on the Item_Command:

```
//Add item command to DataList
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="Item_Command">


  void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
  {

     // Set the SelectedIndex property to select an item in the DataList.
     ItemsList.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
     //Get the selected Item
     DataListItem selectedItem = DataList1.DataKeys[DataListList1.SelectedIndex];
     //Get the label control
     Label myTempLabel = (Label)selectedItem.FindControl("Label6");
     myTempLabel.Visible = true;

     // Not sure if this is needed.
     //ItemsList.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
     //ItemsList.DataBind();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox that gets the value is outside your update panel then try this:

```cs
if (e.CommandName == "selectitem")
{        
    DataList1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    TextBox2.Text = Label)DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
}
```

If the textbox that gets the value is inside your update panel then try this

```cs
if (e.CommandName == "selectitem")              
    ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")).Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```